# JAVA: What is the difference between a logical AND/OR and short circuit AND/OR?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, statements

When I run a simple program, both of them ( & and && ) seem to work interchangeably.  Could someone please explain when I should use each case?

```
 public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        int counter = 0;

        int dice1;
        int dice2;


    for (int loop = 0; loop <= 1000; loop++) {


    dice1= (int) (Math.random()*6)+1;
    dice2= (int) (Math.random()*6)+1;

        if (dice1 == 6 && dice2 == 6){
            counter ++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Counter = " + counter);

    } 
}
```

This program also seems to work when I use & instead of &&.  So what's the difference?

Comment: I don't see any usage of `||` or `|` in your code. Could you share your actual code please?

Comment: i meant & and &&, my bad

Comment: You know that one of them short-circuits. Do you understand what that means? What if your test is `test != null && test.equals("foo")`? Test that.

Comment: The question pointed to by @JBNizet has an accepted answer that is not correct. Since I can no longer answer this question I cannot fully explain the difference. Suffice it to say that a single & operator is a bitwise and where && is a logical and. Also an `if` statement only evaluates boolean operations. Each part of the if evaluates to a boolean. Then if you bitwise & a boolean with another boolean you will get a boolean result. So in this case you will get the same output. But logical evaluations can short circuit whereas bitwise expressions cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that the `&&` and `||` operators do some kind of "lazy evaluation"

In this line of code:

```
method1() & method2();
```

both methods will be called independant of the return value of `method1`. On the other hand in this line of code:

```
method1() && method2();
```

the `method2` will only be called if `method1` returns `true`.

When using `||` the second method will only be called when the first method returns `false`.

---